# Why is the German name for Pineapple, "die Ananas"?

Tags: standard-german

Pineapple is called as Ananas in many languages including Russian and Hindi. How did it get its name as Ananas in German?

Comment: You mean from which original language it was adopted?

Comment: If you check the origin of the word pineapple you will see that it originates in the english language (with very similar words in dutch and german).
I suppose other languages like Russian and Hindi took that word from English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are interested in the **Etymology** of the word. You can quickly find results for that yourself, once you know what you are looking for. Thus:

> From Old Tupi nanas (“excellent fruit”) through Portuguese ananás; influenced by its cognate, Dutch ananas.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ananas#Etymology_2